# Variable from a function to get each changed value

Tags: scala, function, dataset

There are dataset in object. I can change the value, but like this I always get an old map.

```
   var partnerURLs=getPartnerURLs()

  def getPartnerURLs(): mutable.Map[String, List[String]] ={
    val sql = "select * from table where status_flag=1 and del_flag=0"
    val resultSet = DBUtils.doMapResult(sql)
    var result = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, List[String]]()
    resultSet.foreach(rows => {
      val row = rows.asInstanceOf[util.HashMap[String, Any]]
      result += (row.get("uname").toString -> row.get("urls").toString.split(",").toList)
    })
    result
  }
```

If I update the database, the **partnerURLS** can't change, it always has old value.
this method is ok, can get latest value, I want this variable  **partnerURLs** how get the latest value?

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by updating the database? You mean to say that your method getPartnerURLs is not fetching the latest updates from the database?

Comment: this method is ok, can get latest value, I think this variable  partnerURLs how get the latest value?

Comment: Do you understand classes and objects and how they work? If yes, you should know why the global variable partnerURLs do not reflect the latest value! Please understand the basics first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var partnerURLs = getPartnerURLs()
```

This variable is your problem. If it is globally declared in the enclosing class or object, it will be initialized only once!

Also, please avoid using mutable state! Give some respect to Scala and Functional programming!

Comment: It's my problem ,I think the Scala pass the function to the variable,It is a reference call,Not a value of initialized.So how can I defined a function to a variable,I can get value in runtime every call.